# Event code running after a while in Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011, event-system

I have written a event system which will be triggered on any page save to publish it. It shows in the event viewer that the event is initiated but taken 30 mins to 1 hr or more to complete it's execution and log the necessary outcome. Does it take so long to execute. This is the code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Tridion.ContentManager;
using Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events;
using Tridion.Logging;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Templating;


namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [TcmExtension("PagePublishOnItemSave")]
    public class Class1 : TcmExtension
    {
        EventSubscription _subscription;
       public Class1()
        {
            _subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<IdentifiableObject, SaveEventArgs>
                                             (OnItemSavePost, EventPhases.Processed);

        }

       private static void OnItemSavePost(IdentifiableObject item, 
                                    SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
            {             
                IEnumerable<IdentifiableObject> items = new List<IdentifiableObject> { item };
                TcmUri pageid = new TcmUri(item.Id);
                bool rollBackOnFailure = true;
                bool includeComponentLinks = true;
                PublishInstruction instruction = new PublishInstruction(item.Session)
                {
                    DeployAt = DateTime.Now,
                    RenderInstruction = new RenderInstruction(item.Session)
                    {
                       RenderMode = Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.RenderMode.Publish
                    },
                    ResolveInstruction = new ResolveInstruction(item.Session)
                    {
                         IncludeComponentLinks = includeComponentLinks
                    },
                    RollbackOnFailure = rollBackOnFailure,
                    StartAt = DateTime.MinValue
               };
               string publicationId = pageid.PublicationId.ToString();
               Publication publication = new Publication(new TcmUri(publicationId), item.Session);
               PublicationTarget ptar = new PublicationTarget(new TcmUri("tcm:0-11-65537"), 
                                                              item.Session);
               IEnumerable<PublicationTarget> pubTarget = new List<PublicationTarget>() {ptar};
               IList<Publication> links = ptar.Publications;
               if (links.Contains(publication))
               {
                   if (item.Id.ItemType == ItemType.Page)
                   {
                       PublishEngine.Publish(items, instruction, pubTarget);
                       using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(
                                             @"c:\logfolder\Initiated " 
                                             + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmssffff") + ".txt"))
                       {
                           writer.WriteLine(item.Title + " is published");
                           writer.Close();
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
           public void Dispose()
           {
               _subscription.Unsubscribe();
           } 
       }
  }
```

Comment: Try running the code in debug mode.  On the Tridion server, Open Visual Studio and this project.  Attach to the Publisher and/or Tridion Service Host processes and your breakpoint will be hit.

Comment: This should not be the case, it should happen pretty much instantaneously. As per Robert. Try debugging in VS and see if anything becomes clear.

Comment: I don't have the VS installed on Tridion server. Will try to debug remotely.

Answer (score 10):

I may just not be seeing it in the code, but you're not implementing IDisposable and there's nothing in your code calling Dispose(). If you're not disposing of the subscription it never actually finishes executing, as Dispose is what enables garbage collection to clean up all of your references. Have your class implement IDisposable.